# Which files or folders should be in .gitignore in React project?

Tags: reactjs, git, gitignore

I am making a react project and using Linux mint in Laptop and Windows 10 desktop. I would like to know, which files or folders should I keep in .gitignore so that I don't have to clean cache and install npm whenever I switch computers.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Why bother? Just point your browser to [gitignore.io](https://www.gitignore.io/) and select all the tools and technologies you are using. You will automatically have a generated `.gitignore` file.

Comment: The default `.gitignore` for React generated by gitignore.io is very basic and won't cover everything - it doesn't even include the `build` folder. The `.gitignore` from Facebook should cover everything - https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/main/.gitignore

Comment: @ChrisHalcrow that's React's gitignore, it should not be 100% considered an adequate example of a project created with the React Library

Answer (score 13):

```
# Logs
logs
*.log
npm-debug.log*
yarn-debug.log*
yarn-error.log*


# Compiled binary addons (http://nodejs.org/api/addons.html)
build/Release

# Dependency directories
node_modules/
jspm_packages/

# Distribution directories
dist/

# Typescript v1 declaration files
typings/

# Optional npm cache directory
.npm

# Optional eslint cache
.eslintcache

# Optional REPL history
.node_repl_history

# Output of 'npm pack'
*.tgz

# Yarn Integrity file
.yarn-integrity
```

Comment: I'd suggest adding "vendor/" to the "Dependency directories" section.

Answer (score 7):

If you use create react app, then a good .gitignore for react projects is included. You *definitely* want to keep node_modules in gitignore.

Answer (score 3):

See [How to configure .gitignore file](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/) for more detials.

**Dependencies**

```
/node_modules
/.pnp
.pnp.js
package-lock.json
```

**Testing**

```
/coverage
```

**Production**

```
/build
```

**Misc**

```
npm-debug.log*
```

Comment: `package-lock.json` is intended to be checked into source control, don't ignore it!

Answer (score 3):

The closest I can find to an 'official' `.gitignore` is the open source `.gitignore` maintained under the Facebook git repo - https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/main/.gitignore

Answer (score 1):

you can add following files in react gitignore

```
.idea/
.vscode/
node_modules/
build
.DS_Store
*.tgz
my-app*
template/src/__tests__/__snapshots__/
lerna-debug.log
npm-debug.log*
yarn-debug.log*
yarn-error.log*
/.changelog
.npm/
yarn.lock
```

Comment: Suggest not including yarn.lock in your gitignore, your CI/CD tools should be using the same tested versions you've reviewed and accepted. Don't always assume that patches will not break your applications.

Answer (score 1):

this is the *.gitignore* file that **Vite** creates every time you execute:

```
npm create vite@latest
```

You can modify it based on your project's structure.

*.gitignore*:

```
# Logs
logs
*.log
npm-debug.log*
yarn-debug.log*
yarn-error.log*
pnpm-debug.log*
lerna-debug.log*

node_modules
dist
dist-ssr
*.local

# Editor directories and files
.vscode/*
!.vscode/extensions.json
.idea
.DS_Store
*.suo
*.ntvs*
*.njsproj
*.sln
*.sw?
```

Answer (score 0):

node_modules should always go in gitignore and the log files if you have any. Rest is up to you. Theres no such standard